# How to render array of data into multiple mustache partials?

Tags: python, arrays, mustache, pystache

I'm using Python's pystache (which is the standard Mustache api).

Here is an example of my data's structure:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "user": "foo",
      "flags": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ]
    },
    { ... }
  ]
}
```

Now in my template I try to do this:

```
{{#results}}
    {{> stuff}}
{{/results}}
```

Where `stuff` is a partial, and that partial looks like this:

```
user: {{ user }}
isX: {{ flags.x }}
```

Now what provides the data to the template is a class that acts as a 'view model' so I can normalise some of the data and have the template interact with the normalised data rather than the raw json data shown above.

The problem is I don't know how to implement my view model to work with the fact we're looping through nested data.

Using the above as an example, my raw data uses an array of strings to represent the `flags` value, where as I want the template to show true or false depending if the value `x` appears in the flag array.

In code I might try to implement this like so:

```
class Feed(Presenter):
    def prepare_view(self, **params):
        self.view = View()
        self.view.template_path = '/app/static/views/feed.mustache'
        self.view.results = self.post.results
        self.view.flags = namedtuple('_', ['x'])('true')
        return self
```

> just imagine the `namedtuple` was where I loop over the array looking for the `x` string and I return true or false based on that

Now the issue here is that for me to write the `namedtuple` code, I need to know *which* index of the results to be looping over.

Am I just missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've managed to resolve this issue myself with a change in code design and nesting 'Presenter' classes (but I would be interested to see how others are doing this; as I tried multiple other ways trying pystache language features with no working solution)...

```
class Feed(Presenter):
    def prepare_view(self, **params):
        self.view = View()
        self.view.template_path = '/app/static/views/feed.mustache'
        self.view.teasers = self.prepare_teasers()
        return self

    def prepare_teasers(self):
        return [Teaser(Context(result)) for result in self.post.results]
```

> where `self.post` is set on the `Presenter` and provides the raw data we're looking to consume

The `Teaser` then works effectively the same as this top level `Feed` presenter, the difference is it's given a different 'context' object (i.e. `self.post` value) to use as its data source:

```
class Teaser(Presenter):
    def prepare_view(self, **params):
        self.view = View()
        self.view.template_path = '/app/static/components/teaser/teaser.mustache'
        self.view.username = self.post.author
        self.view.uri = self.post.uri
        self.view.title = self.post.name
        return self
```

> `self.post` is now one of the elements from inside `self.post.results` from the top level `Feed` presenter

Our code starts at the top level presenter (`Feed`) and starts recursively rendering each nested Presenter it finds

Answer (score 0):

In pure Javascript based Mustache template I would do this:

```
var results = fetchFromApi();
results['flags_icon'] = function(){
    if ( this == 'x') { return "fa fa-times";/*font awesome icon*/}  
}
var html = Mustache.to_html($("#mytemplate").html(), results);
```